# Hresult 0x80070003 - ASP.NET Web Aplication (.Net Framework) - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

This is my first post on stackoverflow because i don't see the solution anywhere.

The problem is, when i want to create a ASP.NET Web Aplication, this error appears. Please i need help, i'm sure this is a simple error but i can't make it works for start working in my proyect.

The proyect is created but that error makes dont work correctly.

The project creation parameters are as follows:

1)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwalH.png

2)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPHJx.png

And here the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi0gN.png

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to save VS related things in a OneDrive folder. Thus, use a normal folder and test again.

Comment: That was the problem maybe, for now it works. Thanks! @LexLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lex Li for the reply.

From the project creation parameters you provided, the project location is in the OneDrive folder.

It is recommended that you create or use a normal folder to store the project and test again.

If the problem persists, please contact me again.

Answer (score -1):

I would do a repair of the vs2022 install.

I am able to choose your options - works without issues.

So, go tools->get options and

close the first panel, and then choose this:

[image]